# Perl not identifying the folder

Tags: perl

Perl is not detecting the existing folder, folder already exists but still it is not detecting at all.

Below given is the simple code

```
my $dir = '/net/prihpwnfs02';
if (-e $dir and -d $dir) {print "GOOD :)\n";} else {print "BAD :(\n";}
```

Comment: using perl, version 5.005_03 built for sun4-solaris

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking what error you got.

```
my $dir_qfn = '/net/prihpwnfs02';
defined( my $is_dir = -d $dir_qfn )
   or die("Can't stat \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");

print $is_dir ? "GOOD :)\n" : "BAD :(\n";
```

or

```
my $dir_qfn = '/net/prihpwnfs02';
stat($dir_qfn)
   or die("Can't stat \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");

print -d _ ? "GOOD :)\n" : "BAD :(\n";
```

If you don't want to die if it doesn't exist,

```
my $dir_qfn = '/net/prihpwnfs02';
stat($dir_qfn)
   or $!{ENOENT} or die("Can't stat \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");

print -d _ ? "GOOD :)\n" : "BAD :(\n";
```

---

The message "*Value too large for defined data type*" is associated with error `EOVERFLOW`. The `stat`(2) man page defines when it returns this error. On my system, it says the following:

> [The argument] refers to a file whose size, inode number, or number of blocks cannot be represented in, respectively, the types `off_t`, `ino_t`, or `blkcnt_t`.  This error can occur when, for example, an application compiled on a 32-bit platform without `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` calls `stat()` on a file whose size exceeds `(1<<31)-1` bytes.

In short, the fact that you're using an insanely outdated build of Perl is catching up to you.

Comment: Can't stat "/net/prihpwnfs02": Value too large for defined data type
It is showing this error

Comment: ok, that's a first for me! I've updated my answer with an explanation of the message. In short, the fact that you're using an insanely outdated built of Perl is catching up to you.

Comment: I dont want to upgrade perl because it is a very old Server don't we have any alternative

Comment: Is there any other alternate way of running the code using the existing older version of perl

Comment: No. The builtin `stat` (and `-d` by extension) won't work for that file.

Comment: @user11730572, ouch!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do, since you did not asked an actual question, but if you're trying to check whether a folder exists or not, you could use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $dir = '/net/prihpwnfs02'; 

if (-d $dir) {
    print "$dir exists";
} else {
    print "$dir does not exist";
}
```

Let me know if it helped!

Comment: thanks Carlos its showing as ""/net/prihpwnfs02 does not exist""

Comment: @user11730572 then you probably have a problem with the folder/directory. Try in another folder/directory. It could be a permissions problem maybe?

Comment: I have this folder from very long period and there are many user directories available inside it

Comment: For every other folder it is working except for this

Comment: permissions are ""drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root        4096 Jul  2 09:45 prihpwnfs02""

Comment: Yes it works for /net but not for "/net/prihpwnfs02"

Comment: pwd command ooutput
""/net/prihpwnfs02""
Permissions for this folder
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root        4096 Jul  2 09:45 prihpwnfs02

Comment: Does `ls -la /net/prihpwnfs02` from the shell prompt list the contents of the folder? I'm wondering if there's some weird character in the folder name (like a newline or a trailing space)

Comment: I checked and could not find any weird character in the folder

Comment: ls -la /net/prihpwnfs02
total 25
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root        4096 Jul  2 09:45 .
dr-xr-xr-x   5 root     root           5 Jun 11 10:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x  24 root     root        4096 Jan 14 12:10 export

Comment: `print "$dir does not exist";` is incorrect. `-d` returning false doesn't necessary indicate the file doesn't exist.